# indexing XML Solr Schemaless mode

Tags: xml, solr, lucene, schemaless, solr-schema

I'm using Solr in schemaless mode, and I want to index some XML files, using the *post* command via shell.

I've configured in *solrconfig.xml* the *ManagedSchemaDefinition* and commented the *ClassicIndexSchemaFactory*.

The post command index successfully files:
    bin/post -c mycollection server/solr/docs/*.xml

where *docs* is a folder in which I've insert the XML files I want to index into *mycollection*.

The problem is that in *mycollection* overview, *Num Docs=0*, and also in *SchemaBrowser* tab there aren't fields of the XML indexed.

Am I missing some configuration steps?

Comment: Are you actually typing `.xml*`? This will only match files that start with .xml as their name. You might be thinking of `*.xml`?

Comment: Obviously, It was a mistake. I've updated the post with the correct formatting.